# How to get a reference on a ctypes struct class (or its _fields_ parameter) from a 'parent' pointer (meta) class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Assume the following:

```
import ctypes

class Point(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ctypes.c_double),
        ('y', ctypes.c_double)
        ]

def some_routine(struct_pointer):
    # Do something to get '_fields_' from structure behind struct_pointer
    print(_fields_)

some_routine(ctypes.POINTER(Point))
```

In my scenario, both `class Point` and `some_routine` are buried in different modules. Therefore, I have not found a way to retrieve the fields' definition of `class Point` from within `some_routine`. How can this be done?

Comment: You can use `stuct_pointer._type_` to reference the `Point` class.

Comment: ``_type_`` was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you use _type_ to print out the elements of Point in a different module ?